# Use %20 instead of + to encode spaces when submitting a form using GET method

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a static HTML page which contains a form. The form will be submitted using GET method. (The URL string will be parsed automatically by our service.)

By default if you enter `hello world` in an input field, the result URL will be something like `xxx=hello+world`

But the requirement is, the spaces should be encoded as `%20` instead of `+`. (like `xxx=hello%20world`)

The only solution I can imagine is to listen onSubmit event, use `encodeURIComponent` to encode all the inputs by myself and use `location.href` to redirect to the result URL.

I feel this way is a little bit.. dirty. Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: *"But the requirement is, the spaces should be encoded as %20 instead of +. (like xxx=hello%20world)"* The requirement is that you can't send a standard URI-encoded form? Sounds like the backend needs fixing, not your form.

Comment: We have some hardware that will capture and parse all the network traffics. The URL string should be able to be decoded

Comment: Currently the `+` cannot be decoded. But yeah.. another solution is to ask them to replace all the `+` to spaces

Comment: If feels dirty because it is but I can't imagine other way to proceed, unless you want (or are allowed) to develop some server-side code to act as proxy. To benefit from time-saving features you have to follow the rules—it you can't, you're on your own :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is the standard way to encode spaces in [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type). The backend should be handling them properly.

> The only solution I can imagine is to listen `onSubmit` event, use `encodeURIComponent` to encode all the inputs by myself and use `location.href` to redirect to the result URL.

If you cannot get the backend updated to handle them properly, sadly, your only option is indeed that. Of course, any clients with JavaScript disabled will send the form in th usual fashion; to prevent that, you might want to have the form unavailable by default and only made available by JavaScript on the page.

[This section of the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) addresses how to serialize the form controls; some notes (but double-check with the spec):

- You'll need to use `encodeURIComponent` on field *names* as well, not just values.
- `disabled` fields are not included.
- Fields without `name`s are not included.
- Fields are included in *document order* (the order you'll see them in a `querySelectorAll` on the form).
- A checkbox is omitted entirely if not checked; if it's checked, its name and the encoded version of its `value` (or `"on`" if it has none) are included.
- Repeated fields with the same name are just included as repeats, e.g. `&field=value1&field=value2`.
- `type=button` and `type=reset` buttons are not included.
- `type=submit` buttons are only included if that button was used to submit the form. You'll need to watch for the `onclick` on the button in order to know that you should include the button's value, since forms can be submitted other ways.